# What is the UK equivalent of a PC 2 laboratory?

Tags: biology, lab-management

In New Zealand and Australia we use the term 'physical containment' (PC) to describe structures and procedures designed to prevent the release of viable organisms into the environment. As far as I am aware, a PC 2 laboratory deals with microorganisms which would be considered human pathogens. Does anyone know what the equivalent laboratory would be called in the UK?

Comment: Is this not equivalent to the internationally used "biosafety level" (BSL) 1-4?